# Git equivalents of most common Mercurial commands?

Tags: git, mercurial

I've been using Mercurial but would like to do a quick demo of Git.

What are the Git equivalents of:

```bash
hg init . # start a project in the current directory
hg addremove # look for any added or deleted files
hg commit -m "comment" # commit any uncomitted changes
hg status # what have i changed since the last commit?
```

Comment: I would be curious to see a table showing all the equivalent commands between at least the popular DVCSes, if anyone happens across one while coming up with an answer here.  I didn't find one in a quick Google search.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[The Git-HG rosetta stone is not bad](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone)

There are a few other gotchas between the two not mentioned there. This list was cribbed from my own blog post when I went the other way (git -> hg).

**Hg** `.hgignore`, syntax: glob is the same behaviour as git's .gitignore.

**Git** `.git/config`, `~/.gitconfig`, use git-config to modify the values
**Hg** `.hg/hgrc`, `~/.hgrc`, use `hg help -c config`

**Git** `git commit -v<br>`
**Hg** `hg diff | less; hg commit`

**Git** `gitk<br>`
**Hg** `hg view, or thg from [TortoiseHg][1]`

**Git** `git gui<br>`
**Hg** Mercurial doesn't ship GUI to select changesets, only console `hg record` command.

**Git** `git rebase<br>`
**Hg** [hg rebase](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RebaseExtension). For `git rebase --interactive` there's [hg histedit](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HisteditExtension), or Mercurial Queues

**Git** `git push URL ; git remote add origin URL<br>`
**Hg** `hg push URL; $EDITOR .hg/hgrc ; [paths] default = URL`

**Git** `gitk, git log origin/master..HEAD<br>`
**Hg** `hg outgoing`

**Git** `git format-patch RANGE<br>`
**Hg** `hg email -m filename -o`

**Git** `git add . ;` Note the dot
**Hg** `hg add ;` No dot needed.

**Git** `git checkout REVISION-KEY<br>`
**Hg** `hg update CHANGESET`

Just to fill the blanks, some of the most useful commands from Mercurial:

**Hg** `hg record`
**Git** `git add -p; git commit`

**Hg** hg inc [URL]
**Git** No real equivalent. You can only do equivalent of `hg pull; hg log -r .:`

**Hg** `hg out URL`
**Git** Please add if you know how.

For merge conflict resolution, the `hg resolve` command in Mercurial has a few options that change the behaviour:

**Hg** `hg resolve -m FILE` (marks the file as having been resolved by manually fixing up the conflict problem)
**Git** `git add FILE`

**Hg** `hg resolve -u FILE` marks the file as having been unresolved
**Git** `git reset HEAD FILE` to unstage the file

**Hg** `hg resolve -l` (lists files with resolved/unresolved conflicts)
**Git** `git status` - files that merged cleanly are added to the index automatically, those that are not have conflicts

**Hg** `hg resolve FILE` (after a merge, attempts to re-merge the file)
**Git** no equivalent for re-merging that I know of.

Comment: The real equivalent for `git rebase` is in fact `hg rebase`.  Queues are a more complex thing (they do more than rebase at the cost of more work by the user).  Git has several external tools to do what queues do (`guilt`, stacked Git, etc.)

Comment: For gitk there is a graphical clone for Mercurial, hgview (note that it is different from the "hg view" command)

Comment: A small suggestion: swapping the Hg and Git text around (as it's Git for Mercurial users)

Comment: Hg outgoing is not equivalent to a git log filter. It simply lists what changes would be pushed to the given URL without having to pull from there first to update the remote pointers. Git gui's functionality is a graphical one, and as such it should be compared to TortoiseHg's hunk selection/shelve feature.

Comment: Although `hg record` is not very user-friendly, `hg crecord` (from [crecord extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CrecordExtension)) is a curses-based text UI that is extremely easy to use.

Comment: @ozzy432836 I haven't used Hg for years now, but I think those are the resolve equivalents. FWIW the default action of `hg resolve` is one of the reasons I prefer git. By default `hg resolve` destroys your nicely manually resolved merge if you pass it no arguments!

Answer (score 50):

Note: one of the biggest difference between Git and Mercurial is the explicit presence of the **index** or **staging area**.

From [Mercurial for Git User](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts#Git.27s_staging_area):

> Git is the only [DistributedSCM](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DistributedSCM) that exposes the concept of index or staging area. The others may implement and hide it, but in no other case the user is aware nor has to deal with it.
>
> Mercurial's rough equivalent is the [`DirState`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/DirState), which controls working copy status information to determine the files to be included in the next commit. But in any case, this file is handled automatically.
>   Additionally, it is possible to be more selective at commit time either by specifying the files you want to commit on the command line or by using the [`RecordExtension`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension).
>
> If you felt uncomfortable dealing with the index, you are switching for the better ;-)

---

The trick is, you really need to understand the index to exploit fully Git. As this [article from May 2006](http://www.jdl.com/papers/Embrace_The_Git_Index.pdf) reminds us then (and it is still true now):

“If you deny the Index, you really deny git itself.”

Now, that article contains many commands which are now simpler to use (so do not rely on its content too much ;) ), but the general idea remains:

You are working on a new feature and starts to make minor modifications on a file.

```
# working, add a few lines
$ git add myFile
# working, another minor modification
$ git add myFile
```

At this point, your next commit will embark 2 minor modifications in the current branch

```
# working, making major modification for the new features
# ... damn! I cannot commit all this in the current branch: nothing would work

$ git commit
```

Only records the changes added to the staging area (index) at this point, not the major changes currently visible in your working directory.

```
$ git branch newFeature_Branch
$ git add myFile
```

The next commit will record all the other major changes in the new branch 'newFrature_Branch'.

Now, adding interactively or even splitting a commit are features available with Mercurial, through the '`hg record`' command or other extensions: you will need to install [`RecordExtension`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RecordExtension), or the [`CrecordExtension`](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CrecordExtension).
But this is not part of the normal workflow for Mercurial.

Git views a commit as a series of "**file content** changes", and let you add those changes one at a time.
You should study that feature and its consequences: Most of Git power (like the ability to easily [revert a merge (or bisect the problem, or revert a commit)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078146/re-doing-a-reverted-merge-in-git), [contrary to Mercurial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265944/backing-out-a-backwards-merge-on-mercurial)) comes from that "file content" paradigm.

---

[tonfa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/148532/tonfa) (in in profile: "Hg dev, pythonist": figures...) chimed in, in the comments:

> There's nothing fundamentally "git-ish" in the index, hg could use an index if it was deemed valuable, in fact `mq` or `shelve` already do part of that.

Oh boy. Here we go again.

First, I am not here to make one tool looks better than another. I find Hg great, very intuitive, with a good support (especially on Windows, my main platform, although I work on Linux and Solaris8 or 10 too).

The index is actually front and center in the way [Linus Torvalds works with a VCS](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg427450.html):

> Git used explicit index updates from day 1, even before it did the first merge. It's simply how I've always worked. I tend to have dirty trees, with some random patch in my tree that I do *not* want to commit, because it's just a Makefile update for the next version

Now the **combination** of the index (which is not a notion seen only in Git), *and* the "content is king" paradigm makes it [pretty unique and "git-ish"](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#head-3aa45c7d75d40068e07231a5bf8a1a0db9a8b717):

> git is a **content tracker**, and a file name has no meaning unless associated to its content. Therefore, the only sane behavior for git add filename is to add the content of the file as well as its name to the index.

Note: the ["content", here, is defined as follows](http://lists.zerezo.com/git/msg425812.html):

> Git's index is basically very much defined as
>
> - sufficient to contain the total "**content**" of the tree (and this **includes all metadata: the filename, the mode, and the file contents are all *parts* of the "content", and they are all meaningless on their own!**)
> - additional "stat" information to allow the obvious and trivial (but hugely important!) filesystem comparison optimizations.
>
> So you really should **see the index as *being* the content**.
>
> **The content is not the "file name" or the "file content" as separate parts. You really cannot separate the two**.
>   Filenames on their own make no sense (they have to have file content too), and file content on its own is similarly senseless (you have to know how to reach it).
>
> What I'm trying to say is that git fundamentally doesn't *allow* you to see a filename without its content. The whole notion is insane and not valid. It has no relevance for "reality".

From [the FAQ](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitFaq#head-3aa45c7d75d40068e07231a5bf8a1a0db9a8b717), the main advantages are:

- commit with a fine granularity
- help you to keep an uncommited modification in your tree for a reasonably long time
- perform several small steps for one commit, checking what you did with `git diff`, and validating each small step with `git add` or `git add -u`.
- allows excellent management of merge conflicts: `git diff --base`, `git diff --ours`, `git diff --theirs`.
- allows `git commit --amend` to amend only the log message if the index hasn't been modified in the meantime

---

> I personally think this behavior shouldn't be the default, you want people to commit something that is tested or at least compiled

While you are right in general (about the "tested or compiled" part), the way Git allows you for branching and merging (cherry-picking or rebasing) allows you to commit as often as you want in a temporary private branch (pushed only to remote "backup" repository), while re-doing those "ugly commits" on a public branch, with all the right tests in place.

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally "git-ish" in the index, hg could use an index if it was deemed valuable, in fact mq or shelve already do part of that. I personnaly think this behaviour shouldn't be the default, you want people to commit something that is tested or at least compiled.

Comment: About what is in a Git index, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084921/what-does-the-git-index-exactly-contains/4086986#4086986

Comment: In Mercurial your last commit (before push) acts like git's index. You can amend it, roll it back, change commit message or finalize it by changing it's phase to public.

Answer (score 12):

Mercurial:

```bash
hg init . # start a project in the current directory
hg addremove # look for any added or deleted files
hg commit -m "comment" # commit any uncomitted changes
hg status # what have i changed since the last commit?
```

Git Equivalents:

```bash
git init
git add -A
git commit -am "comment" # -a is not necessary along with the above add -A
git status
```

Comment: I (and I think most git users) use `git add -u` more than `-A`; -u will stage changes for all tracked files, ignoring new untracked files.

Comment: but addremove adds new untracked files :)

Comment: I disagree with that `git status` is equivalent to `hg status`. I am new in Hg and have not managed to get hg`s status work similarly as that of Git.

Answer (score 1):

It is roughly the same, without addremove:

```bash
git init # Start a project in the current directory
git status # Displays both changes and added/removed files
git commit -m "comment" # commit any uncommited changes
```

However, these are commands you would use when working alone. You get into the **neat** stuff when you want to merge your changes with other people's work with `git pull` and `git push`, and related commands.

Comment: and to top it off, use "git show" (same as "git diff" I believe) to see what you have changed since last commit.

Comment: "git show" (with no args) shows you the changes *in* the last commit.  "git diff" shows you the changes *since* the last commit.