# Mercurial <--> git cheat sheet?

Tags: git, mercurial

Is there a cheat sheet or wiki page out there which relates `hg` commands to `git` commands, and vise-versa?

I'd like to know for two reasons: first, I'd like to be able to translate `git`-speak<sup>1</sup> into Mercurial, and second I'd like to be aware of the subtle differences between similar-sounding commands (eg, `hg pull` and `git pull`).

<sup>1</sup> case in point: `git push origin :refs/heads/foo`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git equivalents of most common Mercurial commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450348/git-equivalents-of-most-common-mercurial-commands)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

[Git hg rosetta stone](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone) is pretty extensive

Comment: Link to relevant section: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone#rosetta-stone

Answer (score 13):

You also have quite a complete reference in the Mercurial Wiki itself:

[**Mercurial for Git users**](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GitConcepts)

Answer (score 10):

*Disclaimer: I work for Atlassian.*

We have a less comprehensive cheat sheet comparing equivalent/similar SVN, Git & Hg commands in our blog post comparing [Git to Mercurial](http://blogs.atlassian.com/2012/02/mercurial-vs-git-why-mercurial/?s=).

Comment: Great, I would also like the vice versa

Answer (score 7):

There's one at [Hyperpolyglot](http://hyperpolyglot.org/version-control).