# Mercurial to Git

Tags: git

I have more experience working with Mercurial than Git, however, it seems that the project I am working on currently will require me to use Git. I have been looking forward to trying out Git for quite some time too.

Any good resources which you think might help a mercurial user get up and running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a Mercurial plugin called [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/):

> This is the Hg-Git plugin for Mercurial, adding the ability to push to and pull from a Git server repository from Mercurial.

It may save you a switch to another VCS.

If you do want to start using Git, there are plenty of tutorials available, some of them have already been mentioned in this thread. Also, you may find this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450348/git-equivalents-of-most-common-mercurial-commands) useful.

Answer (score 2):

- [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/)
- [Pro Git](http://progit.org/)
- [git ready](http://gitready.com/)

This are the three sources I used and it worked well :) Ive buyed "Pro Git" and it was worth it.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you are more familiar with Mercurial than Git. Then, I would suggest you read [GitConcept](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts), an essay talking about the difference between them and it does really make something clear for you then.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the site: http://gitready.com/
They have great tipps for beginners and also for experienced users.

A book recommendation would be "Pragmatic Guide to Git":
[http://www.amazon.com/Pragmatic-Guide-Git-Guides/dp/1934356727/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356727)