# How can I learn to understand how Mercurial works, as an experienced git user?

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I've been using git for a while now, and since it is the only DVCS I have ever used, I've learned to rely a lot on the way it works for my workflow.

I'm in a new company now, and they use Mercurial, so I need to understand Mercurial's model and how it differs from git, to adapt my workflow and avoid making costly mistakes.

So what resources can I use for this?

Comment: As there is no staging, commands are quite simpler. (Note: Staging is really fine for patch reviewer and merger, all others have to add more flags to do simple things.)

Comment: I don't think the lack of staging area is going to be a big difficulty. I'm more concerned about the branching model and the interaction between remote repositories.

Comment: My comment was more on the commands and the reason why they have less flags. (`git diff HEAD` -> `hg diff`)

Comment: One of the key differences is that you don't need to think about the guts. It just works for the most part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Quite extended [concept differences from Mercurial's official wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GitConcepts).

Another question from *stackoverflow*: [Git equivalents of most common Mercurial commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450348/git-equivalents-of-most-common-mercurial-commands)

#### Comment follow up:

If I resume: "*model*", "*differences*", "*philosophy behind the differences*" and influences on the "*workflow*". In the differences I can think of, there is:

- For the workflow, except the lack of staging area, you should be able to stick on your old practices (when to commit, when to branch, when to merge,...).
- The main difference of philosophy about branches is that Git clones only the specified branch when Mercurial clones all branches (if you want only one branch, it is possible, but it needs configuration).
- The merge philosophy is not really different. Git can merge two or more heads, but Mercurial can only merge two heads (did you ever merge more?).
- The philosophy about renames differs greatly and each designer did defend his point of view. As Mercurial tracks renames, merge can be easier. Git tries to guess renames at merge time if you use the strategy "recursive".
- Storage differs greatly in implementation, but not in concepts (as you asked for "model", I will put more details):

  - Git stores data as ["objects"](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) ("commit object", "tree object", "blob object" or "tag object", stored as file uniquely identified by there name which is a SHA1 hash). This is some kind of "filesystem hash table". With recent versions, those objects can be packed to have less small files under the `.git/objects` directory. I will not go further, my understanding stop here as I never found use to know how bits are laid. You can have a pretty printing in the object's content with:

    ```
    git show -s --format=raw <commitid> # changeset content
    git ls-tree <treeid> # list tree content
    git show <fileid> # blob content
    ```
  - Mercurial [stores](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/behind-the-scenes.html#x8-640004) history of each files individually as "filelog" in the ["revlog(NG)" format](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Revlog). You can manually inspect file names under `.hg/store/data` (revlogNG). Note that special and uppercase characters are "tilda-underscore encoded".

    You can list revisions of a file with:

    ```
    hg debugindex .hg/store/data/<file>.i # hg debugindex <file> also works but you see less of internals
    ```

    You have already noted that the `nodeid`s are not the one in `hg log`.

    And now, inspect the contents with:

    ```
    hg debugdata .hg/store/data/<file>.i <nodeid>
    ```

    The revision history (more or less what you see with `hg log`) is stored in `.hg/store/00changelog.i` (inspect it with `hg debugindex .hg/store/00changelog.i`, you will see the same IDs as the one in `hg log` in the `nodeid` column). To show one raw history entry with id `XXXX`, type `hg debugdata .hg/store/00changelog.i XXXX` in a terminal. (look at first line, it will be used later as `YYYY`)

    The state of the tree is stored in `.hg/store/00manifest.i`. The corresponding `nodeid` in the manifest is `YYYY`.

    ```
    hg debugdata .hg/store/00manifest.i YYYY
    ```

    This will show a list of "filename+nodeid" appended. Let's choose file `foo/bar` and note the `nodeid` appended to it and consider it is `ZZZZ` (line `foo/barZZZZ`).

    Last step, access to the content of the `foo/bar` file:

    ```
    hg debugdata .hg/store/data/foo/bar.i ZZZZ
    ```
  - For the differences in philosophy clearly visible from this basic data storage analysis:

    - When Git commits, it make (potentially a lot of) new files (which can be packed later). When Mercurial commits, it appends to existing files.
    - In Git a `blobid` can collide with a `treeid` (or `commitid` or `tagid`) but that is highly improbable. In Mercurial, a `changesetid` can collide only with another `changesetid` (ditto for manifests (tree) and files (blob)) which is even more improbable.
- In Git, tags are special objects, in Mercurial, it's just a list in a file in the repository (with some [rules](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag#How_do_tags_work_with_multiple_heads.3F) to know which modified copy of the same tag wins).
- In Mercurial, there is no "amend" or "rebase" by default and it is a design choice (philosophy?), always append, never remove content, as it can cause concurrency problem. But it is possible with extensions.

Comment: I've read the first link and it's a good start, although I'd love to find something with a little more text explaining the philosophy behind the differences. I'm not very interested in "equivalence" of commands, since I can always look that up. I'm mainly trying to improve my mental model of how hg works.

Comment: When you say that a hash collision in git is "highly improbable" I think you need to be more clear. As in it is not currently publicly known to have ever happened and that situation is highly unlikely to every change. At least that seems to be the case to me after looking at the probabilities reported by others. Otherwise great answer and +1