# Mercurial undo merge that has more commits following it?

Tags: mercurial, branch

Have a scenario where we un-intentionally merged a named branch (`ABC`) into our `default` branch.

`hg rollback` is not an option because there have been a couple commits since.

Is there a way to undo this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't publish the repo publicly you can do this

```
hg clone -r (parent1 of bad merge) -r (parent2 of bad merge) old new
```

and delete the old repo.

Comment: This works... thanks!  Now I have a remaining problem: how to get the changesets applied after the bad merge into my newly cloned repository?

Comment: @Steve See my answer. You'll have to "rebase" them on the old head.

Comment: @SteveHorn - One approach for applying changesets is to export them as patches, and then import them where needed.

Answer (score 8):

You're going to need the Mq extension. If you don't have it turned on, do so by adding this to your `Mercurial.ini` or `.hgrc` file.

```
[extensions]
hgext.mq=
```

If you're not familiar with it, the [Mq extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) let's you manipulate history. The good news is, this will allow us to fix your repo. The bad news is that anyone who has a clone of the messed up repo will have to clone it again, because we'll be changing history.

First, go make another clone of your repo to work in, so we don't mess anything up.

Now, find the revision id of the merge changeset (that merged `default` and your named branch). Write it down. We'll refer to it as `changesetM`. Now find the revision id of the next changeset. Write it down. We'll refer to it as `changesetN`.

Once you have those two revision ids, head over to your command prompt and `cd` into your repo. Then type out the following, replacing `changeset[M|N]` with the appropriate revision id.:

```
$ hg qimport -r changesetN:tip
  # This will add all of your changes since the merge to the queue
$ hg qpop -a
  # This pops them all out of your history.
$ hg strip changesetM
  # This removes the merge changeset.
$ hg update -C default
  # Make sure we're on the default branch
$ hg qpush -a
  # Take the changesets in the queue and push them back onto your history.
$ hg qfinish -a
  # Remove changesets from the queue and finalize them as normal changesets.
```

Essentially, you are rebasing the new changesets on top of the default branch, removing the merge changeset in the process. Once you're done, you'll need to push the changes to a new repository on the server, and have your colleagues clone fresh copies.

Lastly, if you have any other Mercurial questions, also check out [kiln.stackexchange.com](http://kiln.stackexchange.com/).

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention: If someone has based changes on something that was only in the other branch, it is possible that `hg qpush -a` will fail. You'll see a `foo.txt.rej` and `foo.txt.orig` file laying around. Unfortunately, you'll have to fix this yourself. To fix it, open the original file, the `.orig` file, and the `.rej` file and choose the right changes to merge in, saving them in the original file. Once you've merged it in, use `hg qrefresh` to update that patch to the new, merged patch. From their, you should be able to run `hg qpush -a` again and continue. If you run into the same error again on another patch, just follow the same process.

Comment: I'm with you until hg qpush -a.  I get the following in the console:
applying xxx.diff
patching file -----
Hunk #1 FAILED at 806
1 out of 1 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects "..."
patch failed, unable to continue
...
errors during apply, please fix and refresh 310.diff

Comment: This destroys history, so it will not work if the mistake has been propagated. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265944/backing-out-a-backwards-merge-on-mercurial

Comment: `hg strip` won't this require a force push. This is not an option if a lot of people pull down the repo.

Answer (score 4):

I came across the following scenario today:

```
@    changeset:   1728:5d703e1051d3
|\   parent:      1727:1a5f73b5edb4
| |  parent:      1720:65ddd0bde225
| |  user:        nn
| |  date:        Wed Feb 27 10:35:00 2013 +0100
| |  summary:     Merge with SomeBranch
| |
| o  changeset:   1727:1a5f73b5edb4
| |  user:        nn
| |  date:        Wed Feb 27 10:34:30 2013 +0100
| |  summary:     lorem ipsum
| |
[some more changesets]
| |
o |  changeset:   1720:65ddd0bde225
| |  branch:      SomeBranch
| |  user:        nn
| |  date:        Wed Feb 27 07:44:46 2013 +0100
| |  summary:     lorem ipsum
```

Where *SomeBranch* should not have been merged into *default*. What we did to solve this, was to use the `backout` command with the `parent` option like so:

```
hg backout --rev=1728 --parent=1727
```

By this you don't *undo* the merge itself: Looking at a branch graph (either with graph log or in TortoiseHg) you'll still see *SomeBranch* going into *default* at r1728. The *result* of the merge is however undone, meaning that the changeset containing the backout (r1729 in my case) is identical to r1727.

Comment: Does this also take care of merge flags?